# Is it possible to protect against csrf without using a backend in angular 6?

Tags: angular, security, csrf

We have a session based api. The company is using laravel to get the api, then send it back to angular 6, the sole reason they are using laravel instead of consuming the data directly is just to protect against csrf.

Is it possible to protect against csrf without using a server side backend? would angular interceptors do the job? there's no tokens, it's x-session.

Comment: since HttpClient, you can implement the client side defend against this attack, but you have to complete the defend in the backend with the XSRF-Token. plus, this attack can take in advantage any XSS vulnerabilities, so this attack is never a 100% defend-able. Just a quick note.

Comment: @dAxx_tbat's why i asked because i was pretty sure i can defend it on the client side. thank you so much for the note

Comment: np, its a good question. I wish people would take the security aspect with much more attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can never trust anything that happens in the browser. You always have to assume that the user has complete control over the browser and can extract, delete & modify data at will.

Any data manipulations or security-sensitive operations need to happen on hardware you control.